# TestNG: get test method for configuration method?

Tags: testng

Is it possible to get test method, which relates to current invoked configuration method in listener, which implements IInvokedMerhodListener:

```
@Override
public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
    if (method.isConfigurationMethod() && method.getTestMethod().isBeforeMethodConfiguration()) {
        ...
    }       
}
```

Comment: What is the goal behind the question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to implement listener, which will be use dropwizard metrics library and generate metrics info

Comment: A clear explanation of why you want to do it would help us.

Comment: I want to measure how long every test(method) takes with all related before and after methods